# Calculating peak period jitter from datasheet that lists phase noise

Tags: clock, phase, rms, jitter

The oscillator I plan on using list phase noise for a 20MHZ signal as:

- (100Hz)   -124 dBc/Hz
- (1kHz)           -140 dBc/Hz
- (10kHz)         -148 dBc/Hz
- 100kHz       -155 dBc/Hz
- (1MHz)         -157 dBc/Hz
- (10MHz)       -158 dBc/Hz

I want to convert this to peak period jitter because this is what is specified for the load.

I used a conversion tool from rf-tools to convert phase nose to RMS jitter. I got .477ps.

I then went to AN10007 app note from Renesas which had a formula for peak-peak jitter from RMS jitter. They had a table based on BER rates as to what multiplier you use. For a 10-12 BER, the multiplier was 14.069.

So I multiplied 14.069 with .477ps to get 6.7ps.

I then compared this to what the load spec said which is +/-150ps peak period jitter, so I concluded that the oscillator is well within the specification of the load.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: Will this be used as a VCXO in a PLL or multiplier? or are you just trying to find the phase margin loss due to clock noise alone?  What is the bandwidth of the signal and PLL? +/-150ps  / 50ns =

Comment: +/-150ps  / 50ns =0.3% is the spec?  which = -50dB.  So the accumulated phase noise integrated over the period of time = 1e12 bits is your total jitter. But a PLL can eliminate noise below BW by negative feedback tracking the data phase detector. spectrum.  So you need to **define the time interval and error correction from a PLL** in a system. Sounds like overkill unless multiplied greatly in a PLL

Comment: Why do you need a -124 dBc/Hz phase noise @ 100Hz for just a 20MHz clock? Is this being multiplied to 4GHz?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a look at [Converting Oscillator Phase Noise to Time Jitter](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-008.pdf).  This document describes the conversion procedure.  I will summarize it below.

RMS Phase Jitter (seconds) = \$\frac{\sqrt{2 \cdot 10^{A/10} }}{2 \pi f_{0}}\$

Where \$A\$ is the integrated phase noise and \$f_0\$ is sampling frequency.

You may also want to try the tool at [Phase Noise to Jitter Calculator](https://rf-tools.com/jitter/) which will directly do the computation for you.  Using that tool and your numbers I come up with slight more than 660 fs, but I don't know the exact details of your use case so I recommend you verify with your specific parameters.  Given that, your answer sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this makes sense?

IMHO not quite, or not really.

You need to define all the system parameters of jitter spectrum of which the clock jitter is small part of the problem.  This is because crystals have a very high Q, much higher than the length of bits used over which phase error can be corrected in the receiver.

So you must define the PLL BW bit rate, detector type and thus sensitivity of clock jitter to bit error. ( single sample vs integrate over the entire bit)

**The preferred system metric for BER is phase margin** **in \$10^x\$ bits** or per message or frame. Clock jitter is the smallest component of the causes of phase margin loss, unless multiplied from MHz to GHz.  Then a design budget is allowed for each cause of loss of phase margin due to jitter. **Phase margin is the % of the total clock or data interval.**

The phase spectrum resembles a 1st order LPF with -20dB/decade and a breakpoint << 1 Hz. The 1/f flicker noise in the low band is added is a 2nd order effect added if it exists until it crosses under 1st order phase noise spectral density response.

Phase noise is a Lorentzian model for the white noise
sources and Gaussian for the flicker noise source.

**The standard deviation of the jitter after \$\Delta t\$ seconds is
proportional to  \$\Delta t\$.**

### Details not discussed

https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-01984/technical-overviews/5990-3108.pdf

Using @GrapefruitIsAwesome 's link my results below.

[image]

You don't really want to compute the phase error of 1e12 bits open loop but rather use the PLL BW  to reject the clock noise corrected below that in the PLL's BW. *So that has to be defined.*

### Comments

For a 20 Mbps clock and data stream, the phase jitter only has to be <1% outside the PLL BW and not 150 dB down.

If there is low-frequency jitter in the data from the asymmetry of time-variant skew or crosstalk or ISI bit-shift that the clock is tracking and thus adding to the jitter or loss of phase margin.   This does not always occur, but depending on the system design, **it is possible for data jitter and clock tracking data to add to the overall loss in phase or window margin.**  Given Gaussian noise then it is possible to estimate BER from any short-term Window Margin measurement by extrapolating the -dB/decade loss in Window margin.

Answer (score 1):

You never mention a carrier frequency in your question, and the RMS jitter cannot be calculated without this parameter: see formulas in [AN-815 Understanding Jitter Units](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/815-understanding-jitter-units), page 9, section **RMS Phase Jitter**. Let us unwrap these formulas, starting from the final one:
$$
\text {RMS Jitter(sec)} = {\frac {\text{RMS Phase Jitter(radians)}} {2·\pi·f_{carrier}}}
$$
Notice the parameter \$f_{carrier}\$ in this formula. In the AN-815 document, \$f_{carrier}=311MHz\$; in your answer, you never mention this parameter, and one of the posters defaults this value to 20MHz, the bandwidth of your signal, which might be the case, but most probably it is not.

Back to unwrapping the formulas in the reverse order. **RMS Phase Jitter(radians)** is calculated from your 'list [of] phase noise [values] for a 20MHz signal': you calculate the area \$N\$, \$N\$=**Noise Power (dBc)**, under a phase noise curve, the curve is plotted with your 'list' data from 100Hz to 10MHz. The result units are **dBc**, you convert this value into radians:
$$
\text{RMS Phase Jitter(radians)} = 2\sqrt{10^{(N/10)}}
$$
and use this value in the formula
$$
\text {RMS Jitter(sec)} = {\frac {\text{RMS Phase Jitter(radians)}} {2·\pi·f_{carrier}}}
$$
.

You see how the carrier frequency is used. To understand why it is required for jitter calculations, consult, for example, the course notes [Noise in Voltage Controlled Oscillators](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-776-high-speed-communication-circuits-spring-2005/lecture-notes/lec17.pdf) of the MIT course 6.776 High Speed Communication Circuits or the other books or articles on this subject. Without the carrier frequency, explicitly stated, you cannot even estimate the jitter, much less to calculate the peak-to-peak jitter value.

Comment: not sure what this would be as I only have both datasheets available but nothing about carrier frequency. I do see for the oscillator that the phase noise is measured at 20MHZ. Would this be the carrier frequency?

Comment: You cannot calculate a peak period jitter without knowing your oscillator frequency, which is typically the carrier frequency of your communication link. If not, it should be specified in your project. When one talks about 'a 20MHZ signal', 20MHz indicates a **bandwidth** of the signal, and bandwidth property pertains to the signal, not to the oscillator. The bandwidth *can* be equal to the carrier frequency (for ultra wide band signal), but most often it is not.

Comment: Ok sorry, I got it. The carrier frequency will be 100MHZ.